# TextBlock Width measurement is differed for WinRT and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, winrt-xaml

I need to return width of `GridComboBoxColumn` based on the maximum length of `combotext` mentioned below, which is loaded as its `ItemsSource` . The maximum combotext is "Frankfurt a.M.-Germany-Country" and the width  is calculted in WinRT and WPF as follows:

```
    //Calculate width for maximum display text ComboBox items
        TextBlock TextBlock = new TextBlock()
          {
              FontFamily = FontFamily,
              Margin = Margin,
              FontSize = FontSize,
              TextWrapping=TextWrapping.NoWrap
          };
        //Set the TextBlock display text to combo items text   and initialize Height and Width for TextBlock
        TextBlock.Text = DisplayText;
        var parentBorder = new Border { Child = TextBlock };
        TextBlock.MaxHeight = size.Height;
        TextBlock.MaxWidth = double.MaxValue;
        this.DataGrid.UpdateLayout();
        //Measuer the width and Height of parentBorder 
        parentBorder.Measure(new Size(TextBlock.MaxWidth, TextBlock.MaxHeight));
        parentBorder.Child = null;
        return parentBorder.DesiredSize.Width;
```

In WPF, the width returned as 182.46 and in WinRT the width is returned as 248 . But in WinRT the column width fit with ComboBox, in WPF the ComboBox does not fit inside the column width. Please advise how the size is measured in both WPF and WinRT?

Comment: I think it's due to resolution scaling in WinRT. Look at here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn958435.aspx

Comment: WPF uses inches, WinRT uses pixels.  Apples and oranges.